# How to Rotate or Scale ImageView with Image?

Tags: android, image-scaling, image-resizing, android-imageview, image-rotation

How to Rotate or Scale Image View with Image? Image View's Size is Wrap_Content and Rotate or Scale Image on Touch Event Of Image view.

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Animation` on your ImageView. Here is an example for rotate animation:

```
    Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, ANGLE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setDuration(DURATION);
    anim.setRepeatCount(0);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    image_view.startAnimation(anim);
```

You can find similar solution for Scale and Translate animation. If you don't want to see animation, set duration to zero. The `setFillAfter` is important, if you dont want to reset the image after animation. Good luck

Comment: And what effect you would like to achieve with touch events? Just to launch to rotation, scale after tuching or modify rotation angle and scale by some gesture listener, including multitouch? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Not Multi Touch I have done only Rotation of Image, Scaling of Image & Zoom In,Zoom Out of Image in Touch Event of Image but Problem is if I am Zoom In or Zoom Out the Image that time the only Image is zoom in or zoom out not Image View. so How To Zoom in, Zoom Out, Scale & Rotate Image View with Image.